# html, csrf token tag is not working. Shows in page

Tags: html, django, django-csrf

I'm using django and a static html file.

i add `{% csrf_token %}` tag in my html.

```
<form data-toggle="validator" role="form" action="/form/" method="post">

            {% csrf_token %}
            <!some inputs>
</form>
```

But when i refresh the page there is a text above my form `{% csrf_token %}`
Why html tag is not working?

Comment: Er, because as you said, this is a static HTML file not a Django template. How are you expecting anything different?

Comment: how can i solve this? i want to use it in a static file. is there a solution?

Comment: Don't serve it as a static file. You need some very basic view mapped to a URL display it. Probably /form/.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use JavaScript to get csrf token:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#ajax